# EV3 and HiTechnic Color Sensor Block

Tags: ev3

Can I use the Hitechnic Color Sensor with my EV3?
At the HiTechnic web site I cannot find the necessary files for importing the Hitechnic Color Sensor Block into the EV3 software.

Comment: For 3rd-party product support you might find it quicker to contact HiTechnic via their [support form](http://www.hitechnic.com/support).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is

On the HiTechnic website: => download
http://www.hitechnic.com/downloadnew.php?category=38

This is preliminary release of the HiTechnic EV3 Color Sensor Block.  Note that this block only supports the EV3 and will not work with the NXT.  Zip file includes both the Color Sensor block and a sample program that shows the color sensor values on the EV3 screen.  See instructions at top of this downloads page for installation instructions.